# string to list with no delimiter

Tags: python, loops

To convert the following string to list, I use a for loop:

```
s = "ATCGT"
l = []
for element in s:
    l.append(element)
```

is there a faster way of doing this without for loop in Python?

Comment: What is the reason for turning the string into a list? Strings in python are iterable and mostly act like lists anyway. You can certainly do this with less code, but you can't do it "faster" because a loop will be required.

Comment: The reason is that I want to replace a character at a specific position in the string with sthg else and turning it into a list is the way I could think of. Is there a better way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: Your string looks like RNA. If you are mutating it, then replacing a single index is fine. Just check out the link from Sayse's comment. If you are calculating the complement, then you should build another string, instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call the `list` constructor

```
list(s)
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't run any faster than the explicit loop since the `list` class must still iterate over the string in a loop.

Comment: When I `%timeit` in my notebook, I get with the loop `63.7 ns per loop`, while with the constructor `11 ns per loop`

Comment: Whilst this answers the question posed the OPs comment makes it clear this was an XY problem